# Select blob keys by prefix in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, blob, cql, key-value-store, lexicographic

I am using a Cassandra-compatible database (that is ScyllaDB) I use it purely as a Key-Value Store with keys and values being `Blob`, that is `Vec<u8>` type. That is, it is created by

```
CREATE KEYSPACE kv WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 }
CREATE TABLE kv.pairs (k blob, v blob, primary key (k))
```

I would like to use it to access the keys that begin by a specific prefix. So, if the keys are `[0,1,4]`, `[0,1,5]` and `[0,2,4]` I would like to obtain for the prefix `[0,1]` the keys `[0,1,4]` and `[0,1,5]`.

The condition of being a prefix can be expressed by the lexicographic order on integer vectors, that is we have that `[0,1]` is a prefix of a vector `v` if and only if `[0,1] <= v < [0,2]`.

For integer values, such interval conditions can be expressed very easily. But not so for Blobs where the only available operators are EQ and IN. The `token` function does not seem relevant as it returns a hash and is used for partition hashing. Ideally, I would like to have a query of the following form:

```
SELECT k FROM kv.pairs WHERE [0,1]<=k AND k<[0,2] ALLOW FILTERING
```

In `DynamoDB` we can access the data via the `begins_with` function. Is there anything similar in Cassandra Query Language (actually ScyllaDB is what I use, but it is compatible with Cassandra)? Cassandra seems to discourage the use of blobs but prefix seems a relatively simple notion.